# Reload after div hide

Tags: jquery, reload

I wrote a certain function which produces a certain output in `#foo` using AJAX.
How can I force the page to reload after `#foo` is hidden?

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
     //...
     $('#foo').delay(10000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: you can use `location.reload();` to reload the page

Comment: Yes, what I did not know was that fadeOut() could accept a function as an argument.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fadeOut()` can accept a function as an argument.

For more: http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/.

So try this:

```
$.ajax({                                      
    $('#foo').delay(10000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        window.location.reload(); // to reload page
    });
});
```

Comment: Please explain what the issue is with the code in the question, and why this helps. Remember that we're here to educate people, not just provide code.

Comment: Ok @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 3):

FadeOut accepts function as argument which will execute after fadeOut operation completed.

> .fadeOut('slow', function(){ ... });

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $.ajax({                                      
      .......
    $('#foo').delay(10000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
         // reload page here
         location.reload()
     });
});
```

Comment: Please explain what the issue is with the code in the question, and why this helps. Remember that we're here to educate people, not just provide code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
  $.ajax({                                      
    .......
  $('#foo').delay(10000).fadeOut('slow', "linear", function(){
    location.reload();
  });
});
```

Comment: Please explain what the issue is with the code in the question, and why this helps. Remember that we're here to educate people, not just provide code.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/
as you can see in the link below fadeout function that have 3 parametes,
speed
easing: specify the animation "linear" or "swing"
and a callback executed when the animation complete

Comment: Please edit your question to include that. Also, please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. In this case the jQuery documentation is far more comprehensive and accurate: http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/